# ApplicationSignInManager> retorna valor nullo

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, identity

Este error me da cuando trato de hacer login. 
Me di cuenta que el SiggnInManager me devuelve valor nullo. Ya busque alguna solución pero ninguna funciona. Les dejo el código que utilizo.

```
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    private IdentityUserRole getRoleUser;

    public AccountController()
    {
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _signInManager = value;
        }
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? 
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    // GET: Account
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {            
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var user = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        try
        {      
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }

            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);

            if (user != null)
            {
                IdentityUserRole role;
                if (user.Roles.Count() > 0 && user.Roles != null)
                {
                    role = user.Roles.FirstOrDefault();
                    getRoleUser = role;

                    //Search if the user is active, that the data of column Logical Delete be equals that 0
                    bool userActive = GetUserIsActive(role.UserId, role.RoleId);
                    if (userActive == false)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("invalid_login", "Invalid login attempt.You do not have access to the system");
                        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                        Session.Abandon();
                        return View(model);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("invalid_login", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }

            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("invalid_login", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
            }
        }
        catch (HttpAntiForgeryException)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("invalid_login", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> [NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.]
>      LupitasGroup.CRM.Controllers.d__14.MoveNext() in C:\LupitasGroup\LupitasGroup.CRM\Controllers\AccountController.cs:102
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +102
>      System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +64
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__11_0() +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.b__2() +228
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__3() +35
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +11
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__151_2(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +13
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c.b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +576
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +132
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución a mi pregunta fue la siguiente.

1. Agregue una clase OWIN Startup class en la raíz del proyecto.
2. El contenido de esa clase fue la siguiente

   ```
       using Microsoft.Owin;
       using Owin;

        [assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(NombreDelProyecto.Startup))]
        namespace NombreDelProyecto
        {
        public partial class Startup
        {
              public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
               {
                    ConfigureAuth(app);
                     // For more information on how to configure your application, 
                        visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
                }
         }
        }
   ```
3. La clase Startup que se encuentra dentro la carpeta de App_Star no tiene ninguna modificación.

Les comparto mi solución espero sea de ayuda para alguien.